# Issue transferring JSON code to extern file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, random, append

I have an issue with some JSON code. I try here to randomly append in a `<p>` some strings located in an extern JSON file. I succeed to make it work here on codepen : http://codepen.io/ChucKN0risK/pen/LcFop

The thing is that I didn't succeed to make my code work on an extern JSON file. As I just started to learn JSON I'm not even sure I need a table or just 3 titles with their respective value.

After searching I found that to make it work I had to put my code inside the each event in Jquery.

```
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
    alert(data[i].PageName);
});​
```

However wherever I put my code it doesn't even seem to be taken in count since my console.log test doesn't work.

Here is my javascript code:

```
// Sentences

var p = $('#sentences-wrapper');

$.getJSON('src/js/data.json', function(data) {
    var random = data.sentences[Math.floor(Math.random() * data.sentences.length)];
    p.append("<span>" + random.title + "</span>");
});
```

And here is my JSON code:

```
{
    "sentences": [{
        "title": "la big data"
    }, {
        "title": "développer des applications ergonomiques, simples et sur mesure"
    }, {
        "title": "chorégraphier des services et orchestrer de la donnée"
    }]
};
```

Comment: What is `sentences`? Also, you never use `data`, `index`, or `value` anywhere in your code. How is this ever going to do anything with the data if you never even access it?

Comment: `sentences` are the strings that are supposed to randomly append in my   `<p id="sentences-wrapper"></p>`The `data`, `index` and `value` are quite unknown to me since I just started to learn JSON and javascript in general. How should I use them properly ?

Comment: See my answer in that case.

Answer (score 0):

```
var p = $('#sentences-wrapper');

$.getJSON('src/js/data.json', function(data) {
    var random = data.sentences[Math.floor(Math.random() * data.sentences.length)];
    p.append("<span>" + random.title + "</span>");
});
```

The `data` argument in your getJSON callback should be the contents of your JSON file, already parsed into a JS object. In that case, `data.sentences` should be identical to `jsonContent.sentences` in your codepen example.

Comment: After modifying my code as you suggested the console is still reluctant to show anything :/

Comment: In that case, youre going to have to edit your question to contain the contents of `src/js/data.json` and the JS code that you are using.

Comment: Ok, but why doesn't you're js code match what i wrote, or at least look similar?

Comment: My mistake I forgot to edit my post after that. Unfortunately it still doesn't work :/

Comment: Open up the network tab in chrome Dev tools too see if the ajax call is working. Does the execution of the program make it to the callback?

Comment: Here is a screen. This is the first time I use this tab. It doesn't seem to be working :/ http://www.hapshack.com/?v=JzLxw.png

Comment: Can you click on the one that says invalid and see what it says? Chances are your link should be `/src/js/data.json` with a / in front, as well.

Comment: First, did you add the / to the request url? Second, i don't see this request showing up at all in your network tab. Is it out of view?

Answer (score 0):

In your codepen the json is in 'jsonContent', which has 'sentences' which have titles.

In your getJSON statement, the content of the data.json files gets assignent to the var 'data'

So your titles live in data.sentences.title the correct code should be:

```
$.each(data, function(index, value){
    var random = data.sentences[Math.floor(Math.random() * data.sentences.length)];
    console.log(random.title); // <= should work now
    p.append("<span>" + random.title + "</span>");
});
```

I'm not sure why you added the $.each function. Your Original codepen example prints 1 random sentence from the json.
Using the $.each statement, you append a random sentence for each element (ea sentence) in the json. Which should result in doubles and some others that don't get printed. (EDIT: this is not true, since your json contains only one list of itmes (sentences). and of course you didn't use the value or index. In this case: data.sentences, value, data[index] would all be the same list of titles.)

If you want to print all the sentences in a random order, you have to rethink the code a bit.

Answer (score 0):

After looking in the console I saw that my JSON file was not formatted properly. I had to remove the ";" at the end of my code. http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/. Anyway thanks for your help guys :)

Comment: I have to wait until tomorrow to make validate my answer :/ Do you think I should delete the topic ?